# Logout from JASIG server from browser

Tags: cas, jasig

I am trying to logout from JASIG CAS server running on tomcat.
I access my data from a nodeJS proxy and i have no idea how to logout. 
I tried removing the cookie and it didnt help.

What is the right way to log out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue at - https://github.com/fangli/kibana-authentication-proxy/issues/36